# Opening Microsoft Access with parameters

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-access, ms-office

Similar to the [OpenArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836583.aspx) property of the Form object, am I able to open the Access Application itself with a passed parameter (say from a .bat file)?

Basically I'm looking to speed up the user's experience by having variable links to .bat files that open the same file, but to a different menu screen etc.

Comment: Have a look at https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Command-line-switches-for-Access-558cfe1d-3c98-4292-bee8-1f5df9702bf1

Comment: thanks @Fionnuala. The /x from that site I would have used, but I think the /cmd switch is more useful because I can do all the processing in the start up function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `/cmd` command-line parameter to start Access, and the `Commmand()` function in Access-VBA to read it.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" D:\Work\myDb.accdb /cmd foo
```

and this function called by an `Autoexec` macro:

```
Public Function AutoExec()

    Dim sCmd As String

    ' ... other initializations ...

    ' Read /cmd command-line parameter
    sCmd = Command()

    Select Case sCmd
        Case "foo": Call Foo()
        Case "bar": Call Bar()
        Case Else: Debug.Print "No valid command-line parameter passed."
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this process when the database has a password on it and uses the MS Access 'User Permissions' for `.mdb` files?

Comment: You can specify the .mdw with `/wrkgrp C:\FullPathTo\mysecurity.mdw`. `/cmd foo` must be the last parameter. Specifying the database password via command-line is not possible: [Link](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/12519978-for-security-support-passing-the-database-passwor). @Symon