# Can't capture /cmd value in Access Macro

Tags: ms-access

MS Access (2007 - 2016) in Office 365

I'm trying/failing to capture a value passed into Access from the command line using the Command() function in a Macro.  THis is the macro that I created with the wizard...

```
If Command()="Update_Burndown_Metrics" Then
  RunSQL
    SQL Statement   insert .... blah, blah
End If
```

No error when I save the macro, but when I run...

```
The expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access can't find
```

If I replace the...

```
If Command()="Update_Burndown_Metrics"
```

with

```
If 1=1
```

It runs fine. IOW, it's not the SQL.  It's the "Command() function that it can't find.

I got the idea to use Command() from [Opening Microsoft Access with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176599/opening-microsoft-access-with-parameters) .  Doesn't seem to work for me.  But that coding approach is also confirmed here... http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/Command-Line_Switches .  So I think it's something else.

Eventually, I would like to pass the Update_Burndown_Metrics arg using /cmd on the command line.

Why can't it find Command() as a valid function ?  Is it a scoping thing?  Do I have to give Command() context somehow, maybe with some sort of prefix ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce the issue that you are describing, though, I am using an earlier version of MS Access, and so there may be some differences in the behaviour of this function.

The `Command` function should be globally accessible, even outside of VBA (it can be referenced by the `ControlSource` property of a text box, for example), and so this isn't an issue of scope.

I do observe from the [Office 365 documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-function-fec67826-7fd7-48ed-a7aa-479c020ffaa4), that the `Command` function is being invoked without the use of parentheses in the sample VBA Sub provided; therefore it may be worth you trying your code without including such parentheses, e.g.:

```
If Command = "Update_Burndown_Metrics" Then
    MsgBox "Test succeeded."
Else
    MsgBox "Test failed."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I created is to create a function in vba that gets and returns the command...

```
Public Function GetCommand() As String
  GetCommand = Command()
End Function
```

Then...

```
If GetCommand() = "Update_Burndown_Metrics" Then ...
```